# Ist "geeignet für" hier grammatisch korrekt?

Tags: grammaticality

Ist der Satz grammatisch korrekt?

> Die Kratzer sind mit einem transparenten Lack zu übermalen, geeignet für die Anwendung auf Aluminium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich denke ein ganzer Nebensatz mit Relativpronomen und Verb ist besser verständlich.

> Die Kratzer sind mit einem transparenten Lack zu übermalen, **der** geeignet für die Anwendung auf Aluminium **ist**.

Als eine technische Anleitung/Dokumentation wäre sicherlich auch folgendes Konstrukt denkbar.

> Die Kratzer sind mit einem transparenten Lack (geeignet für die Anwendung auf Aluminium) zu übermalen.

Oder man benutzt eine Fußnote:

> Die Kratzer sind mit einem transparenten Lack<sup>1</sup> zu übermalen.
>
> ...
>
> <sup>1</sup> geeignet für die Anwendung auf Aluminium

---

> das ist eine Bedienungsanleitung

Dann wären zwei Hauptsätze vielleicht sogar die noch bessere Wahl:

> Die Kratzer sind mit einem transparenten Lack zu übermalen. Der Lack muss  geeignet sein für die Anwendung auf Aluminium.

Comment: Richtig, das ist eine Bedienungsanleitung. Ich habe gelesen, dass Relativssätze in der Bedienungsanleitung, falls möglich, zu vermeiden sind. Ich wähle den 2. Satz aus, aber statt Klammern würde ich Kommas verwenden. Danke.

Comment: @Anna dann ist es aber auch nicht besser als der Relativsatz. Generell ist alles zu vermeiden, was einen Satz unnötig verlängert. Alles, was irgendwie mit Kommas abgetrennt werden soll, ist doof. Ob du also nun den Relativsatz oder den Einschub mit Kommas nutzt kommt in der Hinsicht auf's Gleiche raus. Es wären auch zwei Hauptsätze denkbar. (siehe edit) Für die Vermeidung von Wortwiederholungen gibt's in Bedienungsanleitungen keine Bonuspunkte.

Comment: @Anna: Klammern sind meistens ungrammatisch und Deine Wahl von Kommas stattdessen nur zu unterstützen.

Comment: @userunknown wie grammatisch der Text einer technischen Anleitung ist, ist meistens zweitrangig. Wofür genau gab's jetzt die -1? Wegen der Klammern?

Answer (score 3):

Der Satz hat eine ungewöhnliche Wortstellung und ist daher m. E. nicht sofort verständlich, da sich *geeignet für* gefühlt auf das *übermalen* bezieht, was Unsinn ist. Als grammatischen Fehler würde ich das nicht unbedingt bezeichnen, eher schlechten Stil.

Deshalb würde sich diese leicht geänderte Formulierung anbieten:

> Die Kratzer sind mit einem transparenten, für die Anwendung auf Aluminium geeigneten Lack zu übermalen.

Möglicherweise handelt es sich hier auch um eine direkte Übersetzung aus dem Englischen ohne weitere Korrektur/Verbesserung, wo der Lack am Ende des Hauptsatzes steht, und das *geeignet für / suitable for* dann unmittelbar ergänzt werden kann:

> ... covered by a transparent finish suitable for ...

Comment: Das ist eine Übersetzung aus dem Polnischen. Dein Satz ist verständlicher.

Comment: Ich möchte darauf hinweisen, dass das zweite Komma gestrichen werden muss; schließlich ist _für die Anwendung auf Aluminium geeigneten_ kein durch Kommas abzutrennender Einschub, sonder einfach eine zweite, dem Adjektiv _transparent_ gleichrangige Eigenschaft des Lackes.